# GridLayout is showing only one column on some DPI

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin.android

So I have a GridLayout - it's using weight to distribute itself properly. The problem is that it doesn't display correctly on some devices - for example on Xperia E3 (480 x 854, 218 DPI) or 3.7" FWVGA slider in the designer.

Here's how it should always look like:

[image: Looking good!]

Here's how it looks like on some devices (only first column of GridLayout is visible and it gets stretched even beyond the right side of the screen):

[image: Not looking good]

Here's the XML, basically GridLayout contains buttons and the main thing here is that each button has 
`android:layout_columnWeight="1"
 android:layout_rowWeight="1"`

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.3">
        ...
    </RelativeLayout>
<!--Bottom part (buttons)-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.7"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    <!--Scroll bar with all the different functions and constants-->
        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">
            <GridLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="false">
                ...
            </GridLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
    <!--THIS IS THE PROBLEM Main buttons for the calculator THIS IS THE PROBLEM-->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.9">
            <GridLayout
                android:id="@+id/mainBtnGrid"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:rowCount="5"
                android:columnCount="5"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnClear"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_main"
                    style="@style/button_main_calculator"
                    android:text="C"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnSeven"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_main"
                    android:onClick="Button_OnClick"
                    style="@style/button_main_calculator"
                    android:text="7"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnFour"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_main"
                    android:onClick="Button_OnClick"
                    style="@style/button_main_calculator"
                    android:text="4"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"/>
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnOne"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_main"
                    android:onClick="Button_OnClick"
                    style="@style/button_main_calculator"
                    android:text="1"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnSign"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_main"
                    style="@style/button_main_calculator"
                    android:text="±"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnBack"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_main"
                    style="@style/button_main_calculator"
                    android:text="B"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnEight"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_main"
                    android:onClick="Button_OnClick"
                    style="@style/button_main_calculator"
                    android:text="8"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnFive"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_main"
                    android:onClick="Button_OnClick"
                    style="@style/button_main_calculator"
                    android:text="5"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnTwo"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_main"
                    android:onClick="Button_OnClick"
                    style="@style/button_main_calculator"
                    android:text="2"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnZero"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_main"
                    android:onClick="Button_OnClick"
                    style="@style/button_main_calculator"
                    android:text="0"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnTypingPositionSwitch"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_main"
                    style="@style/button_main_calculator"
                    android:text="M"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnNine"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_main"
                    android:onClick="Button_OnClick"
                    style="@style/button_main_calculator"
                    android:text="9"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnSix"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_main"
                    android:onClick="Button_OnClick"
                    style="@style/button_main_calculator"
                    android:text="6"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnThree"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_main"
                    android:onClick="Button_OnClick"
                    style="@style/button_main_calculator"
                    android:text="3"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnDecimal"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_main"
                    android:onClick="Button_OnClick"
                    style="@style/button_main_calculator"
                    android:text="."
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1" />
                <Space
                    android:layout_width="5dp" />
                <Space
                    android:layout_width="5dp" />
                <Space
                    android:layout_width="5dp" />
                <Space
                    android:layout_width="5dp" />
                <Space
                    android:layout_width="5dp" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnDivide"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_operator"
                    android:onClick="Button_OnClick"
                    style="@style/button_main_calculator"
                    android:text="/"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnMultiply"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_operator"
                    android:onClick="Button_OnClick"
                    style="@style/button_main_calculator"
                    android:text="x"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnSubtract"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_operator"
                    android:onClick="Button_OnClick"
                    style="@style/button_main_calculator"
                    android:text="-"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_operator"
                    android:onClick="Button_OnClick"
                    style="@style/button_main_calculator"
                    android:text="+"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnEquals"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_operator"
                    style="@style/button_main_calculator"
                    android:text="="
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1" />
            </GridLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I have no idea what to do with this, I mean, it's not happening constantly! Thank you for reading this, I will greatly appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: `android:layout_columnWeight` and `android:layout_rowWeight` are not supported before Android API 21, have you checked the android version of your device?

Comment: Yes. I've been testing it on emulators with API 25. When I tested it on a physical device with API 19, I tried using GridLayout from the support library and the result was the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found a solution to this problem.

Turns out that you just need to specify
`:layout_width="0dp"`
for **each button**. Then it looks as it's supposed to on all the different screen resolutions and sizes.

I suspect this happens because on smaller screens the grid layout was overflowing even before I've specified

```
android:layout_columnWeight="1"
android:layout_rowWeight="1"
```

***Note**: for **GridLayout v7+** you should use `app` instead of `android` as follows:

```
app:layout_columnWeight="1"
app:layout_rowWeight="1"
```

so it "*didn't know how far it should stretch*".

However, now when the width is set to 0dp, it's no longer overflowing anywhere and that's why adding weights now works flawlessly.

I hope this helps some of you - this was a really frustrating problem to have!